# how to chage ipython folder colours? eg read output from ls command on dark background

Tags: spyder, dark-theme

I would like to use spyder in the dark theme; but some default colours are difficult to read. how do i change them?

specifically using Spyder Dark theme and when I run `ls` in ipython console the folders are in dark blue making it very difficult to read

[image: ls command with dark blue on dark theme]

in the colour scheme editor is not clear which box i need to edit

[image: colour scheme edit]